# how to compare the output from a bash script with a file?

Tags: bash

there is a file, let's call it a reference file, you need to execute the script and compare the reference file with it, a file of 132 kb

```
result=$(./test.sh)| cmp -s $result test && echo 1||echo 0
```

I get the wrong output, the test file is identical to the script output, but I get 0

Comment: What's the point of the pipe (`|`) in your command? There is no command to the left of it, and `cmp` is  ignoring stdin anyway, unless a sole `-` is passed on the commandline (see _man cmp_).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pipe the script's output to `cmp`.

```
./script | cmp -s - file
```